# Communication Containers in a local machine via Rest in php and Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new in docker and spring boot.So,I created 1 docker-compose.yml for my app

```
version: '3'
 services: 
  zookeeper:
   image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"

   kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
   container_name: kafka
   ports:
    - "9092:9092"
   environment:
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  web:
    build:
     context: ./php
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: loginform
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - ./login2:/var/www/html  
    ports:
     - "8081:80"
```

,in which the **web** has a dockerfile for php.
Also in spring boot I created an application.yml.

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
 kafka:
  producer:
   bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
   key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

After that I execute my app and it is run in local machine. Now the problem is that I want to send some data via curl with php in spring-boot but the problem is that i don't know the exact url.
I mean that I try to POST data via curl in

- *http://localhost(or 127.0.0.1):8888/publish*

which is the port for spring-boot. With Postman it works but I want to make it work with php.
Here is also my Controller Spring for Spring Boot.

```
package com.examplekafka.springkafkaproducer;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;



  @RestController
   public class DemoController {

  @Autowired
  KafkaTemplate<String,Book> kafkaTemplate;

  private static final String Topic = "testTopic";

  @PostMapping("/publish")
  public String publishMessage(@RequestBody Book book)
  {
    kafkaTemplate.send(Topic, book);
    return "Published Success";
  }
```

}

Can someone help me to find the right URL for making the communication? I don't know where I have to search or how I declare it. I tried without docker via Xampp and it worked right.

Comment: Is your `SpringBoot` also running in container?

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is probably important background material here.  (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in Docker are generally "this container", so you need to use other services' Compose block names as host names instead.)

Comment: @Muhammad Waqas Dilawar the application.yml file doesn't mean that i have a container? I run it with mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: David Maze Maybe Muhammad has right and the reason is that i don't run a container I confused with the configuration of application.yml file..I saw that I can create a docker file but when I tried to composed it there was a problem I dont remember now but if you are right I may try to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

To refer to other Docker services, you use the service names located under `services:` in your YAML - [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

---

Also

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost` is incorrect, as that property is deprecated in favor of `KAFKA_LISTENERS`, [as per the wiki](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity), but you should be advertising the external hostname of the container (`kafka`), not `localhost`

> I tried without docker via Xampp and it worked right

This is the same as saying "Works on my machine". If you were to deploy that code in any other environment and split your services onto several other machines, it would not, regardless of using Docker.